# Add an image watermark in a Flutter Mobile App

Tags: image, flutter, image-processing, dart

I've been looking through the [image package examples](https://github.com/brendan-duncan/image/wiki/Examples). The example given for drawing an image uses the dart:html package.

I managed to get something to work with a combination of image and dart:ui, but it's running very slow. Does anyone know what might be a better way to go about it?

```
      final double canvasWidth = canvasImage.width.toDouble();
      final double canvasHeight = canvasImage.height.toDouble();
      final ui.Paint paint = ui.Paint();

      final recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
      final canvas = ui.Canvas(
        recorder,
        ui.Rect.fromPoints(
          ui.Offset(0.0, 0.0),
          ui.Offset(canvasWidth, canvasHeight),
        ),
      );

      // draw image to background
      ui.Codec backgroundCodec =
          await ui.instantiateImageCodec(img.encodePng(canvasImage));
      final ui.FrameInfo backgroundFrameInfo =
          await backgroundCodec.getNextFrame();
      final ui.Image backgroundImage = backgroundFrameInfo.image;
      canvas.drawImage(backgroundImage, ui.Offset(0.0, 0.0), paint);

      // Add watermark
      // Get watermark from assets
      final ByteData watermarkBytes =
          await rootBundle.load("images/watermark.png");
      img.Image originalWatermark =
          img.decodeImage(watermarkBytes.buffer.asUint8List());

      // resize the watermark to 1/6th of the smallest dimension (the watermark is a square)
      final int watermarkDimension =
          (min(canvasWidth, canvasHeight) / 6).floor();
      img.Image resizeImage = img.copyResize(originalWatermark,
          height: watermarkDimension, width: watermarkDimension);
      ui.Codec watermarkCodec =
          await ui.instantiateImageCodec(img.encodePng(resizeImage));
      final ui.FrameInfo watermarkFrameInfo =
          await watermarkCodec.getNextFrame();

      // get ui image
      ui.Image watermarkImage = watermarkFrameInfo.image;

      // draw watermark to the canvas
      canvas.drawImage(watermarkImage, ui.Offset(0.0, 0.0), paint);

      // export the recording
      ui.Picture pic = recorder.endRecording();
      ui.Image finalImage =
          await pic.toImage(canvasWidth.floor(), canvasHeight.floor());
      ByteData finalByteData =
          await finalImage.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i've encountered is using image library is quite slow, alternatively, i use RepaintBoundary for screenshot of an certain widget:

wrap your widget inside RepaintBoundary with a key

```
RepaintBoundary(
              key: _repaintKey,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Image.asset(
                    'images/food01.jpeg',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  Icon(Icons.translate,),
                ],
              ),
            )
```

and then write bytes:

```
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
                    _repaintKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
File(tempPath).writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
```

Comment: Thanks for the work around! It's a little awkward but it's seriously a lot faster. I'm loading the images from the camera on to a layer that I can screen shot.

Comment: will the output image will be of good quality?

Comment: just give pixelRatio = 2.0 is good enough, boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 2.0);